# About Constant Timer and Ramp-up time and Error

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

What is the difference between the constant timer and ramp-up seconds in jmeter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ramp-Up period** is set in thread group. It is used to define the time, which JMeter takes to create total no of threads (users).

For example,  this is configuration:

```
Number of Threads (users): 100
Ramp-up Period (in seconds): 10
Loop Count : No
```

That means,10 users will be created in each second. So we will have..

```
10 users after 1st second
20 users after 2nd second
..
..
100 users on 10th second
```

Normally, the ramp-up period is set as per our load-scenario. If we want to increase load slowly and step by step then we will use higher ramp-up value and vice-versa.

---

**Constant Timer** is quite different to Ramp-up period. Constant Timer is used to introduce a fixed delay between consecutive requests. This delay can be implemented at a specific request or for all requests in a controller/thread group etc.

Constant timer is normally used to give delays between requests as in real-time scenarios real-users give delays between doing different actions. So to create real-time scenario we introduce think-time by using constant timers.

Comment: Thanks for provided this info.

Comment: NP, let me know if you need any further info for understanding. and If you find my answer helpful please accept it :)